# How do I get MySQL query-results using -initWithContentsOfURL?

Tags: mysql, xml, iphone

I have a server-side php-script that fetches results from a MySQL table. I am trying to retrieve these results from within an iPhone OS app. I am using the following method:

```
NSURL *myURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.someurl.com/login.php?id=anid"];
NSArray *sqlResults = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:myURL];

//Show me what went into the Array
NSLog(@"%@", [sqlResults ObjectAtIndex:0]);
```

*The NSLog at the bottom is me trying to see what just transpired. The NSLog statement is printing out (null) though -- so I am stuck. My problem is that I don't know what the heck I am trying to do with the NSArray of results and I am probably doing many things wrong. Is an internet connection implied (Have Cellular and Wi-fi)? So, my question is: What should I be doing to get MySQL query-results using -initWithContentsOfURL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In which format is your PHP script returning the MySQL results? It looks as though [NSArray initWithContentsOfURL:] requires the data to be in a very specific 'property list' format. Have you tried to see what output you get if you use NSString instead?:

```
[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:]
```

This should at least show you what you are getting out of your PHP script. Finally, take a take at the [property list format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_list#Mac_OS_X). You may need to perform a transformation in your server side script or parse your PHP result set format on the iPhone as BJ Homer suggested.

Comment: Tried it and it gave me just what I was looking for. -Thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation on `-[NSArray initWithContentsOfURL:]` say;

> The array representation at the
>   location identified by aURL must
>   contain only property list objects
>   (NSString, NSData, NSArray, or
>   NSDictionary objects).

To my understanding, that means that it must be in plist format. If your results aren't in plist format, then try using `-[NSString initWithContentsOfURL:]` instead.  If you then want to split it based on lines, you could call `[downloadedString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"]`